# How to get web site domain name on img request from my server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a pixel, which can be placed at any site. Looks like this:

```
<a href="https://myhost.site"><img src="https://myhost.site/img"/></a>
```

I'm working with express and node, try to get domain name which requested this img. Code looks like this:

```
req.get('origin')
```

But it gives me `undefined`. From chrome dev tools in network tab I really see that this request doesn't have an origin header. It looks strange to me. Is there a way to get `domain name` from this get img request?

I can't use `JS`. I have to assume user switched off `js` in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `req.get('origin')` access headers property like `req.headers.origin`.
`

Comment: Log all headers values and see what's coming - `console.log(req.headers)`.

Comment: host it's my express server